# In ASP.Net MVC routing, how can you route 2 different paths that look the same, but have different types?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

In ASP.Net MVC, I want 2 different routes:

http://mysite.com/foo/12345

and

http://mysite.com/foo/bar

In the class Foo, I have 2 methods that return ActionResult

```
public ActionResult DetailsById(int id)
{
. . . some code
}
```

and

```
public ActionResult DetailsByName(string name)
{
. . . some code
}
```

How do I set up 2 routes so that if the parameter is an int, it goes to DetailsById, but otherwise goes to DetailsByName?

Comment: Of course you realize that you can distinguish the different naming methods in your controller, right? This doesn't answer your question though, and I'm also interested in an answer

Comment: Yeah, I guess I did, though I can't say that I've ever used it. I'm not sure how that would affect this question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a route constraint for the first route.

```
routes.MapRoute("DetailsById",
                "foo/{id}",
                new { controller = "foo", action = "DetailsById" },
                new { id = @"\d+" } // Parameter constraints
            );

routes.MapRoute("DetailsByName",
                "foo/{id}",
                new { controller = "foo", action = "DetailsByName" }
            );
```

The first route will only accept ids that match the regex (which accepts numbers only). If it doesn't match the first route, it will go to the second.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "DetailsById",
    "Foo/{Id}",
    new {controller="Foo", action="DetailsById"},
    new {Id= @"\d+" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "DetailsByName",
    "Foo/{Name}",
    new {controller="Foo", action="DetailsByName"}
);
```

Remember that the routes are checked from top to bottom and stop at the first match.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you already have a default route set up for your id parameter.
The only thing you will need to do is add a map route in your global.asax.cs:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Foo_DetailsByName",// Route name
    "Foo/DetailsByName/{name}",// URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Foo", action = "DetailsByName", name = String.Empty  }  // Parameter defaults
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, this can be accomplished through a route constraint. A common scenario is the ability to have my domain.com/482 behave the same way as my domain.com/products/details/482, where you do not want the 482 to be matched as a controller but as a Product ID.

Route constraints are regular expressions, though, so while you can use regex to match the pattern of the route, you are not actually matching based on data type.

See: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-a-route-constraint-cs