# Simple routing issue, optional not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to make a lookup controller with multiple get actions.
My routing configuration is:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "DefaultApi",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "LookupsApi",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional  });
```

My lookup Controller is

```
[HttpGet]
public LookupsList GetAllStates()
{

}

[HttpGet]
public LookupsList GetAllSources()
{
//method
}
```

When I use following it will give nothing but error stating "Multiple actions were found that match the request"

```
http://localhost:51042/api/lookups/GetAllStates
or 
http://localhost:51042/api/lookups/GetAllSources
```

but when I use

```
http://localhost:51042/api/lookups/GetAllStates/1
or 
http://localhost:51042/api/lookups/GetAllSources/1
```

It will work fine.

How can I set my route to work this correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: I had a similar question a wee while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5591569/284111

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a clash in your routes I think.  For example:

```
http://localhost:51042/api/lookups/GetAllStates
```

will match the first route.

You should reverse the ordering of your routes:

Update from [EdSF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/304683/edsf):

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "LookupsApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Additional helpful references:

1. [Route order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#how_urls_are_matched_to_routes)
2. [Route params](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7149774/304683)

Comment: By removing first route lookups controller worked fine. but now 2nd controller is not working

Comment: 2nd controller is public RegistrationModel Get() and I was using it like api/registration but now it says "resource you are looking for has been removed"

Comment: put your default route last in the ordering, it should fall through.

Comment: Removed my answer as all of it has been combined here.